# Embed private Google map on restricted access page

Tags: google-maps

I'm setting up a site with a **members only section**. In this section, I would like to embed a Google Map I'm managing. My understanding is the map must be made public to be able to embed it. The problem is I wouldn't want people who don't have access to my members only section to just use the map link and access it from anywhere, or when they no longer have the member privileges.

A feature I would like to keep is the **layers** that can be set up in the new google maps engine to categorize the elements/points on the map.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [commercial use FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_commercial). I have highlighted the key terms below:

For example, if your site meets any of the following criteria you must purchase the appropriate Google Maps API for Business license:

- Your site is ***only available to paying customers.***
- Your site is
  ***only accessible within your company or on your intranet.***
- Your application relates to enterprise dispatch, fleet management,
  business asset tracking, or similar applications.

Comment: Thanks for the tag edit, as well as the answer, however I was already aware I couldn't just use the lite version for commercial uses. My question is more on the technical side - the integration of a password protected page with a map only viewable from that page.